# How to make a reusable PopupMenuButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a reusable PopupMenuButton in flutter, so i can call that widget and assign the PopupMenuItem dynamically.

Here is what i've done, but it throw a framework error. I am relatively new in flutter.

here is class that supposed to be reusable:

```
class PopupMenu {
  PopupMenu({@required this.title, @required this.onTap});

  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
}

class PopupmMenuButtonBuilder {
  setPopup(List<PopupMenu> popupItem) {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: (_) {
        popupItem.forEach((item) => item.onTap);
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        popupItem.forEach(
          (item) {
            return <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
              PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: item.title,
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and then i call the widget like this:

```
child: PopupmMenuButtonBuilder().setPopup([
              PopupMenu(title: 'Item 1', onTap: () => print('item 1 selected')),
              PopupMenu(title: 'Item 2', onTap: () => print('item 2 selected')),
            ]),
```

It shows the 3 dot icon button, but when i tap the icon it throws this error:

```
I/flutter ( 8509): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8509): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 8509): 'package:flutter/src/material/popup_menu.dart': Failed assertion: line 723 pos 10: 'items != null &&
I/flutter ( 8509): items.isNotEmpty': is not true.
I/flutter ( 8509): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 8509): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 8509): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 8509):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 8509): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8509): #2      showMenu (package:flutter/src/material/popup_menu.dart:723:10)
I/flutter ( 8509): #3      _PopupMenuButtonState.showButtonMenu (package:flutter/src/material/popup_menu.dart:898:5)
I/flutter ( 8509): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
I/flutter ( 8509): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
I/flutter ( 8509): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
I/flutter ( 8509): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
I/flutter ( 8509): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7)
I/flutter ( 8509): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
I/flutter ( 8509): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20)
I/flutter ( 8509): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
I/flutter ( 8509): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
I/flutter ( 8509): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)I/flutter ( 8509): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)I/flutter ( 8509): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
I/flutter ( 8509): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
I/flutter ( 8509): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8509): Handler: onTap
I/flutter ( 8509): Recognizer:
I/flutter ( 8509):   TapGestureRecognizer#8968f(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, won arena, finalPosition:
I/flutter ( 8509):   Offset(339.0, 54.0), sent tap down)
I/flutter ( 8509): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: onSelected: popupItem.forEach((item) => item.onTap);

Comment: that make a syntax error `The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be used.
Check if you are using the correct API; there may be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which, in rare cases, may be void as well.dart(use_of_void_result)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `itemBuilder` needs to return a `List`. It doesn't actually return anything - note how the `return` is inside the `forEach` so it's just returning from the lambda. In general, `forEach` should sometimes [be avoided](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal). Also, the `PopupMenuButtonBuilder` class is redundant - it could be replaced with a static or top-level function.

One other thing that's unclear is why you want to call each `onTap` for every select. As you currently have it it's going to call every callback!

Try this:

```
class PopupMenu {
  PopupMenu({@required this.title, @required this.onTap});

  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  static PopupMenuButton<String> createPopup(List<PopupMenu> popupItems) {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: (value) {
        popupItems.firstWhere((e) => e.title == value).onTap();
      },
      itemBuilder: (context) => popupItems
          .map((item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: item.title,
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a changeable list to append to the Popup menu instead of manually creating it one by one in the child

```
child: PopupMenu(popUpList: _popUpList).createPopup()),
```

then in the Popup menu class

```
class PopupMenu {
 const PopupMenu({this.popUpList});  
 final List<PopUpList> popUpList; 

 PopupMenuButton<String> createPopup() {
   return PopupMenuButton<String>(
     onSelected: (value) {
       popUpList.firstWhere((e) => e.title == value).onTap();
     },
     itemBuilder: (context) => popUpList
         .map((item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
       value: item.title,
       child: Text(item.title),
     )).toList(),
   );
  }
}
```

model

```
class PopUpList{
  String title;
  VoidCallback onTap;

  PopUpList({this.onTap, this.title});
}
```

cheers!